# Grub Bootloader of kali linux automatically gets removed frequently

Tags: linux, multi-boot, bootloader

I have Acer 64bit laptop with windows.I recently dual booted kali linux on it and set the BBS priority on Kali.At starting I could select the OS from Grub bootloader  menu but now I am having problem.The pc starts in windows using windows boot manager without asking for OS.Kali bootloader is also removed from BIOS firmware settings.Then I reinstalled Kali and problem was solved but only for some days.

Comment: You need to understand UEFI and how it boots. Also understand that Windows feature updates tend to change the boot stanza back to Windows (reason: it often requires several reboots). Once you understand these matters you won't need to post uninformed questions.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia I understand that,I didn't update my windows after dual booting and it happened many times  that grub bootloader was removed

Comment: Are you sure it was removed? Have you checked the boot order in UEFI settings? Some Acer models are notorious for being dual boot unfriendly but for some there are workarounds. But you need to do your homework and that is googling your exact model plus Debian or Ubuntu, instructions should fit Kali as well. You won't find many results if any at all with Kali because 1) Kali is not meant to be installed and/or used as a regular desktop Linux and 2) is intended for professionals only, not to someone posting this kind of questions.